# UNIDENTIFIED OPERATION FIELD JCL

Tags: jcl, zos

I am trying to understand where I am going wrong in my JCL file.
Here is my code as follows:

```
//MULTG013       JOB  1,NOTIFY=&SYSUID
//STEP1           EXEC PGM=ICEGENER
//SYSUT1        DD DSN=UNTG013.DATAIN(AUTODATA),DISP=SHR
//SYSUT2        DD DSN=UNTG013.DATAOUT(MULTIOUT),DISP=SHR
//SYSPRINT      DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN         DD DUMMY
//STEP2           EXEC PGM=IDCAMS
//SYSPRINT      DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN         DD *
    DELETE      UNTG013.DATAIN(AUTONEW)
/*
//STEP3           EXEC PGM=IDCAMS
//SYSPRINT      DD SYSOUT=*
//OLDINV        DD DSN=UNTG013.DATAIN(AUTODATA),DISP=SHR
//NEWINV        DD DSN=UNTG013.DATAIN(AUTONEW),DISP=SHR
//SYSIN         DD *
    REPRO INFILE(OLDINV)    OUTFILE(NEWINV)
/*
//STEP4           EXEC PGM=IDCAMS
//SYSPRINT      DD SYSOUT=*
//STUFF         DD DSN=UNTG013.DATAIN(AUTONEW),DISP=SHR
//SYSIN         DD *
    PRINT INFILE(STUFF) CHAR
/*
//STEP5           EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01
//SYSPRINT      DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSTSPRT      DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSTSIN       DD *
    RENAME     'UNTG013.DATAIN(AUTONEW)' 'UNTG013.DATAIN(ITDSDATA)'
/*
//STEP6           EXEC PGM=IDCAMS
//SYSPRINT      DD SYSOUT=*
//STUFF         DD DSN=UNTG013.DATAIN(ITDSDATA),DISP=SHR
//SYSIN         DD *
    PRINT INFILE(STUFF) CHAR
/*
//STEP7           EXEC PGM=IDCAMS
//SYSPRINT     DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN        DD *
    DELETE     UNTG013.DATAIN(ITDSDATA)
/*
//
```

The error I am getting on the SYS Z is:  IEFC605I  UNIDENTIFIED OPERATION FIELD, lines 17 & 25.

Not quite sure how it is incorrect.  Thanks

OK. Here is the message from spool:

---

SDSF OUTPUT DISPLAY MULTG013 JOB02122  DSID     4 LINE  NOT PAGE MODE DATA
 COMMAND INPUT ===>                                            SCROLL ===> PAGE 
********************************* TOP OF DATA **********************************
 STMT NO. MESSAGE
       17 IEFC605I UNIDENTIFIED OPERATION FIELD
       25 IEFC605I UNIDENTIFIED OPERATION FIELD
******************************** BOTTOM OF DATA ********************************

also just found this as well.

SDSF OUTPUT DISPLAY MULTG013 JOB02122  DSID     2 LINE  NOT PAGE MODE DATA
 COMMAND INPUT ===>                                            SCROLL ===> PAGE 
********************************* TOP OF DATA **********************************
                   J E S 2  J O B  L O G  --  S Y S T E M  S 0 W 1  --  N O D E

17.59.22 JOB02122 ---- FRIDAY,    28 MAR 2014 ----
17.59.22 JOB02122  IRR010I  USERID UNTG013  IS ASSIGNED TO THIS JOB.
17.59.22 JOB02122  IEFC452I MULTG013 - JOB NOT RUN - JCL ERROR  415
------ JES2 JOB STATISTICS ------
           41 CARDS READ
           45 SYSOUT PRINT RECORDS
            0 SYSOUT PUNCH RECORDS
            2 SYSOUT SPOOL KBYTES
         0.00 MINUTES EXECUTION TIME
******************************** BOTTOM OF DATA ********************************

Hope this helps and thanks for the input thus far!  I am still looking into it as well to see if I can figure it out on my own.

Comment: We need to see the JCL from spool file two, where you get the IEFC605I message. If there is no JCL there, add MSGLEVEL=(1,1) to the JOB card.

Comment: Since I could see no errors, I ran your JCL (changing dataset names). It ran without problems. Without the JCL that should appear with the messages, showing the actual JCL used and the line numbers JES thinks there are, we can get no further with this. You must edit your question to include these details.

Comment: Thanks, but you need the MSGLEVEL=(1,1) on your JOB card, so that you see the JCL as it has been processed along with those messages in file two of the spool output.

Comment: I think there is your answer from @piet.t. How did you get tabs into your JCL? Did you prepare it off the Mainframe, and then transfer the JCL to the Mainframe. If so, you need to be careful. Also, did you never use the ISPF editor on your JCL - that would warn you about non-display characters. Are you submitting the JOB from off the Mainframe using FTP?

Answer (score 3):

When looking at the source of your JCL as posted on SO I see TABs between `//STUFF` and `DD` in the two `STUFF`-lines. If they are there in your original JCL as well try replacing them by spaces. With JCL Blanks and TABs are not interchangeable.

Comment: Good spot. That matches my manual count, line-number to STUFF DD's. When I copy/paste it works. Nothing visibly wrong. I think you've got it. How tabs got there is another thing...